# How to define what will be inserted in share message?

Tags: facebook, share

I have an app with blog records per each user. I have add share button to my app, to give ability to post interesting blog records to users time line or to send to other user. But in default it takes image and text for share as it wants and not always correctly. So I find out that it can be dirven by meta tags (using for example "image" property to set image for share dialog). That's work ok on main page (where I'd like to make ability share with whole application), but on pages of blog records I cann`t customize it. meta tag should be in , but all info (short text and image of blog post) I get later in body, so I can insert it. How can I manage with this? Or may be there is another way to share content with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What blog engine are you using? If it is a wordpress - try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-share-new/ from offician facebook docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/. Otherwise I'd suggest to find a facebook plugin for your blog engine using google and install it.

Comment: It`s not a standart blog, it`s my own. So I need to invent something to get info about blog in head, before it will apear in body. That' main problem.

Comment: Then yes, you have to insert this data somehow in your page <head></head>. If you are an author of your blog engine, then you are probably have better knowledge how to do so :)